# How to change default Midnight Commander appearance, so I don't have to change it every time I launch a terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, mc

I have problems with my screen, so I can't see very well using a default MC theme. Switching to the darker one helps me a lot. So that would be great if I could set it as a default theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After switching theme in Options->Appearance it should normally be saved in ini file, so next time you start `mc` previously set appearance will be loaded.

There might be some issues with file / directory permissions so `mc` cannot write changes to ini file.

Midnight Commander version on Gentoo stores local changes in `$HOME/.config/mc/ini`. There, in `[Midnight Commander]` section directive:

```
skin=dark
```

is responsible for proper skin

Comment: Also worth mentioning **Auto save setup**: "If this option is enabled, when you exit Midnight Commander, the configurable options of Midnight  Commander  are  saved  in  the  `~/.config/mc/ini` file."